# Creating an NDVI time series in GEE using Landsat 5 & 7

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have used code from an example by Tim Assal, who used Landsat 8 imagery, but adapted this for my area (the Eastern Cape, South Africa).

Everything works fine but I need to go back as far as possible for my time series (late 1970's) so need to use Landsat 5 and/or 7 in my study area.

However, when I change the code to use Landsat 7 data (see below), it doesn't show the NDVI.

```
//Import Macubeni boundary
//Add Macubeni boundary to layer

Map.addLayer(boundary,{color: 'green'},'boundary');

// load all Landsat 7 SR image within boundary 
var l7collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
          .filterBounds(boundary)  
          .filterDate('1999-01-11', '2013-03-30');

print(l7collection);
Map.addLayer(l7collection);

// Mask pixels with clouds and cloud shadows using the 'pixel_qa' band
// that is based on the cfmask for surface reflectance. 
// https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-surface-reflectance-quality-assessment

// create function to mask clouds, cloud shadows, snow
var maskClouds = function(image){
// make a new single band image from the pixel qa band
var pixel_qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
// retain clear (0) and water (1) pixels
return image.updateMask(pixel_qa.eq(322));   
};

// use "map" to apply the function to each image in the collection
var l7masked = l7collection.map(maskClouds);
print(l7masked);

// // create function to add NDVI using NIR (B4) and the red band (B3)
var getNDVI = function(img){
return img.addBands(img.normalizedDifference(['B4','B3']).rename('NDVI'));
};

// // map over image collection
var l7ndvi = l7masked.map(getNDVI);

// // for each pixel, select the "best" set of bands from available images
// // based on the maximum NDVI/greenness
var composite = l7ndvi.qualityMosaic('NDVI').clip(boundary);

// //set visualization parameters for NDVI            
var ndviParams = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(composite.select('NDVI'), ndviParams, 'NDVI image');
```

Comment: There's a mistake in your `maskClouds` function. The last line should be `return image.updateMask(pixel_qa.bitwiseAnd(32).eq(0));`

Comment: Thank you so much - It worked!